# Folder and File copy

Tags: file, loops, copy

I would like to have you help create a script that i can use to move files from folders that i have. multiple files and have them moved to a set of directories 10 in total. which then loops around that the 11th file would be copied to the first directory like the example below:

```
1.txt      folder 1
2.txt      folder 2
3.txt      folder 3
4.txt      folder 4
5.txt      folder 5
6.txt      folder 6
7.txt      folder 7
8.txt      folder 8
9.txt      folder 9
10.txt     folder 10
11.txt     folder 1
12.txt     folder 2
13.txt     folder 3
14.txt     folder 4
```

I would need the 1.txt move to folder 1 then 2.txt to folder 2 and so thru 10.txt to folder 10 then have 11.txt move to folder 1 then 12.txt move to folder 2 then 13.txt move to folder 3.

Comment: Any particular technology that you plan on using. Also the target platform might help

Answer (score 0):

The actual implementation will depend on the platform you write the script on (here is a javaish snippet), but general logic would be something like this.

```
String[] fileNames = getFileNames(); //some method to retrieve all files your interested in or just pass in as argument`
String[] folderNames = {"folder1","folder2","folder3","folder4","folder5", "folder6","folder7","folder8","folder9","folder10"};

    int i = 0;

    for (String fileName : fileNames)
         if (i == 9)
             copyFile to folderNames[i]
             i = 0
         else
             copyFile to folderNames[i]
             i++;
```

This should at least get you started, obviously left out the copying of files but thats not what you asked about.  This is just simple logic to loop around a array to produce your effect desired.

Comment: i was hoping i can use either a VBscript or a batch file that will comprise a single click to send off to level 1 support that will be able to follow a set of instructions to complete the tasks for engineering